# Range.Find does not work when Sub is called by event?

Tags: excel, vba, events, range

I have done some macro with VBA. In the worksheet there is a Sub called `TSBCalculation`. In the Sub I have the following command inside a `For`-Loop.

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("EHT").Range("A:A").Find(today - i)
```

When running the macro manually whith a Shortcut this command works perfectly fine and I get the rigth result out of it.

To make work easier I want to automatically call the Sub by an event. I have tried the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event and the `Worksheet_Change` event. When the Sub `TSBCalculation` is called by one of these two events the command `Set Rng = Worksheets("EHT").Range("A:A").Find(today - i)` can't find results anymore although it is all the same appart of calling the Sub by event and not executing the macro manually by shortcut for example.

Do anybody of you know what the problem can be?

Comment: You really should specify more parameters of [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), specifically `LookIn` and `LookAt`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant code part or a [mcve]. One line of code is not enough.

Comment: Yes, the Range variable ```Rng``` is empty when the ```Sub``` is called by ```Event```. When i execute the ```Sub``` manually the ```Rng``` is filled with the correct data. I added all arguments which are usefull for this statement. ```Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EHT").Range("A:A").Find(today - i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)```
But unfortunately it still doesn't work. I think it has something todo with the event, is it possible that the data isn't available when the event executes the Sub. So the event is too fast or something like that?